# How do i reduce an array in Angular using a lambda statement?

Tags: angular

I have an object array `LeaveRequests[]` and a LeaveRequest has a field named totalHours. I'm trying to reduce this array to the sum of all totalHours fields.Then i'm assigning this to a numerical variable called `pendingLeaveHoursTotal`

Right now the code looks like this:

```
this.pendingLeaveHoursTotal = this.leaveRequests.reduce((a,b) => a.totalHours+b.totalHours,0)
```

Its using a lambda to do the sum work, however it gives a syntax error. My question is, is it possible to use a lambda statement or do I need to define a function first and add that as an argument to the reduce method together with a start number (in this case 0)?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: when I omit the comma and the 0 it gives me the error `assigne expression LeaveQuery is not assignable to type number`. When I don't omit it says `unresolved variable totalHours`

Comment: sorry, I pushed add comment too quickly. Please see my edited comment

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the `.reduce()` function is the result so far, which is a number in this case, not an object. The function body should therefore be `a + b.totalHours`.

```js
function Demo() {
  this.leaveRequests = [{totalHours: 1}, {totalHours: 2}];

  this.pendingLeaveHoursTotal = this.leaveRequests.reduce((a,b) => a + b.totalHours, 0)
  
  console.log( this.pendingLeaveHoursTotal );
}

new Demo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like I have to use the map function first to transform each LeaveQuery into a totalHours number.

```
      this.pendingLeaveHoursTotal = this.leaveRequests.map(value => value.totalHours).reduce((a,b) => a +b ,0)
```